# Optaplanner / Timefold cloning a Solution

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I have a optaplanner/Timefold solution which works. It provides a solution with a real time feedback during the day to the business. But request for changes get queued in ad hoc, so I need to clone the solution to test if any request has a feasibly solution, before submitting it further into the main solution. For this I clone the current best solution to use for the test as follows:

```
SolutionDescriptor solutionDescriptor =  SolutionDescriptor.buildSolutionDescriptor(DistributionSolution.class, MoverEntity.class, LoaderEntity.class );
        FieldAccessingSolutionCloner<DistributionSolution> distSolCloner = new FieldAccessingSolutionCloner<>(solutionDescriptor);
        DistributionSolution clonedSolution =   distSolCloner.cloneSolution(currentDistributionSolution);
```

But it seems fragile to hardcode the solution and entity classes, I could use the solverConfig.xml but thats another sort of hard coding, it can be moved to a factory etc. But I am looking for a more dynamic way of getting an initialized SolutionCloner. I looked at the TimeFoldProcesser.class as it seems to make exactly that using reflection, but not sure how to access it at run time ? Any idea on how to go around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that `SolutionDescriptor` is not public API; you are doing something you shouldn't have been doing in the first place.

I'm not entirely sure why you need to do any of this; if you want to check that any particular problem has a feasible solution, you should run the solver. Nothing prevents you from running multiple solvers at the same time - one for your actual problem, and another to test a hypothesis.

That said, Timefold Solver will introduce a feature very soon that will help you with this; we call it the Recommended Fit API and it is designed to give super-fast answers to your question: "where best can I put this new entity in my current solution?"

Wrt. "hardcoding entity and solution", I do not understand that part of the question at all. The configuration needs to be written *somewhere* - doesn't matter if it's in `SolverConfig` or if it's in `solverConfig.xml`; it has to be somewhere.

Wrt. `TimefoldProcessor` - if you're using Quarkus, you're already using it; it is an implementation detail of our Quarkus support. If you're not using Quarkus, there is no way to use it.

Comment: You should never need to explicitly clone a solution. I explained what you should do instead.

Comment: ok. the problem is that "I need the clones to" produce new solvers under the same solvermanager, as i have many possible ad hoc request. As proposals for new jobs arrive that ask if a job can be scheduled in various slots ,and I need to test each one hence i may need to process 10 or more alternatives based on the allready populated solution which is running during the day in question. They will not submit a new job unless they know in advance that the solution will not become unrealistic. ?

Comment: I honestly do not understand why you can not submit that to the solver manager. It can run many jobs in parallel. If you receive a solution you don't like, throw it away. If you try to circumvent the solver, I can not help you.

Comment: Well, maybe i can. I would like to use it in the intended way, but i have a running solution, that I need for smaller time adjustments which runs realtime, then theese request for new jobs comes in parrallel, I dont see that i can sumbit a series of new jobs without changing the running job, if its not a cloned first, as the new job-request start off as a 'brach' of the running job and its state  ?

Comment: The working solution is automatically cloned; the input solution you have on the outside will not be changed by the solver, the solver operates on its own clone.

Comment: Oh, so it clones it twice! The input solution is cloned to a working solution then yet again it cloned everytime it find a best solution, in that case it makes sense. i'll try.

Comment: Testet it out, and i works, as you said, it is cloned by the solvermanger before start, hence I dont need to. thx

Comment: +1 on making cloning part of public API.  Clearly, the timefold APIs are the main workhorse for the optimization part, but when preparing tests, custom benchmarks and other analytical workflows, cloning a solution is a versatile and useful tool.